# Why my variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, babylonjs

I am a beginner in javascript, and I don't know why my variable is undefine.

Here is my code:

```
function createBlockMap(data) {
//console.log(data.X + " " + data.Y + " " + data.food);

    var makeOverOut = function (mesh) {
        mesh.actionManager = new BABYLON.ActionManager(scene);
        mesh.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.SetValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPointerOverTrigger, mesh.material, "diffuseTexture", mesh.material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("../assets/GrassLight.jpg", scene)));
        mesh.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.SetValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPointerOutTrigger, mesh.material, "diffuseTexture", mesh.material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("../assets/Grass.jpg", scene)));
        mesh.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.InterpolateValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPointerOutTrigger, mesh, "scaling", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 1), 150));
        mesh.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.InterpolateValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPointerOverTrigger, mesh, "scaling", new BABYLON.Vector3(1.1, 1.1, 1.1), 150));
        mesh.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.SetValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPickTrigger, button2Rect, "levelVisible", true))
        .then(new BABYLON.SetValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnPickTrigger, button2Rect, "levelVisible", false));
    }

    var blockInfo = function (data) {
        box = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("crate", 1, scene);
        box.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("Mat", scene);
        box.material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("../assets/Grass.jpg", scene);
        box.position.z = data.Y;
        box.position.x = data.X;
        box.position.y = 3;
        ownfood = data.food;
        console.log(this.ownfood);
        console.log(data.food);
        Linemate = data.Linemate;
        Deraumere = data.Deraumere;
        Sibur = data.Sibur;
        Mendiane = data.Mendiane;
        Phiras = data.Phiras;
        Thystame = data.Thystame;
        makeOverOut(box);
    }

    var button2Rect = new BABYLON.Rectangle2D(
        {   parent: canvas, id: "buttonClickRes", x: 250, y: 250, width: 100, height: 40, fill: "#4040C0FF",
        roundRadius: 10, isVisible: false,
        children:
        [
            new BABYLON.Text2D("Food: " + blockInfo.ownfood, { id: "clickmeRes", marginAlignment: "h:center, v:center" })
        ]
    });

    if (map[data.Y] == null)
    {
        map[data.Y] = new Array();
    }
    map[data.Y][data.X] = blockInfo(data);}
```

Why blockInfo.ownfood is undefine on "button2Rect" even if I assign "data.food" on the blockInfo function and how can I solve this.

Thanks

Comment: you assign `data.food` to the global variable `ownfood`, not to the property of object `blockInfo`

Comment: And how can I assign the property of blockInfo ?

Comment: The blockInfo is a function, and in JavaScript the function scope (the 'this') is determined by the caller of the function, so you can't really attach properties from inside. Consider returning an object instead, with the properties you need, or use a variable defined in an upper scope - but global states are not really a good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Issue**

When you define a variable inside a function scope, that variable is a local variable that you can use inside of that scope, but will not be accessible outside of that scope later on
so, just because you did

```
function hello(){
  var greeting = 'hi';
}
```

does not mean that you can later access `greeting` such as by doing

```
hello.greeting
```

**Second Issue**

In Javascript, functions are similar to classes insofar as you can create instances of functions. `blockInfo` is a function, not an *instance* of a function. If you want to create an instance of a function, you can do:

```
myBlockInfo = new blockInfo(data)
```

if you simply do

```
myBlockInfo = blockInfo(data)
```

without the `new` keyword, you are not creating an instance of the function (and, furthermore, the value of myBlockInfo will be undefined because the function `blockInfo` does not return anything).

There is a special variable in Javascript: `this`. When you are planning on instantiating a function using the `new` keyword, you gain the ability to use the special variable `this` inside the function. It is a placeholder for "the current instance of the object". So, if you do

```
function blockInfo(data){
  this.ownfood = data.food 
}
```

what you are doing is assigning `data.food` to any instances of that function you might create. So, when you instantiate the function, you will be creating an instance of the function that has a property, `ownfood`, which you can access via the instance:

```
myBlockInfo = new blockInfo(data)
console.log(myBlockInfo.ownfood)
// logs the value of data.food
```